# why is GetComponent<ICameraControl> returning null?

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript

As you can see in the attached image below and the code, I have added a class that implements the interface `ICameraControl` attached to a `GameObject`.

When I call `var controller = GetComponent<ICameraControl>();`, I get nothing returned (null), as in this example:

```
public class KeyboardHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        var controller = GetComponent<ICameraControl>();
        if (null == controller)
            print("no ICameraControl found!");
    }        
}
```

And the output is like this in the unity console:

> no ICameraControl found! UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
>   Assets.Player.KeyboardHandler:Start() (at
>   Assets/Player/KeyboardHandler.cs:18)

Here's the `Camera Position Handler` attached to my game object:
[image]

Here's the interface implementation:

```
public class CameraPositionHandler : MonoBehaviour, ICameraControl
{
    private GameObject mainCamera;
    private Quaternion homePosition;

    private void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
        homePosition = mainCamera.transform.rotation;
    }

    private void LateUpdate() { } 
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Much appreciated :)
Matt

**Edit**:  The keyboard script is on my player object (at bottom of the picture of the player object).  And the Camera Position Handler is on the Camera Arm object.  The Player object and Camera Arm objects are at the same level.

[image][image]

Comment: Your KeyboardHandler script is not visible on the object with your ICameraControl script. Can you show us what object your KeyboardHandler is on, and its relationship to your ICameraControl within the scene hierarchy?

Comment: @DMGregory yes.  See update.  I hope that answers your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consulting [the docs on `GameObject.GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html):

> Returns the component of Type `type` **if *the game object* has one attached**, `null` if it doesn't.

So when your `KeyboardHandler` script says `GetComponent<ICameraControl>()`, that's equivalent to:

```
this.gameObject.GetComponent<ICameraControl>()
```

ie. "Give me an instance of component **attached to the same `GameObject` as I am**, that implements the `ICameraControl` interface"

But you don't have an `ICameraControl` component on the `KeyboardHandler`'s game object, so the method correctly returns null.

It looks like what you might have meant was either:

```
cameraObject.GetComponent<ICameraControl>()
```

which would look for an `ICameraControl` on *some other* object you've provided, either via an Inspector reference or by looking it up with eg. `Camera.main`.

Or, the nuclear option:

```
FindAnyObjectByType<ICameraControl>()
```

which searches your whole scene for any instance of a matching type, attached to any object.

(Note: I've updated this answer from a previous version which used `FindObjectOfType`. In Unity 2021.3.18 and later, `FindAnyObjectByType` is a faster option.)

Comment: Yeah.  I tried 'FindObjectOfType<ICameraControl>()' before asking the question.  I get the following compile error: `The type 'Assets.Scripts.ICameraControl' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Object.FindObjectOfType<T>()'`.   I admit I didn't spend a ton of time researching the error.  I moved on to trying other things.

I wanted to keep hard coded references to implementation types out of my code, if possible.  maybe that is not possible and have to get the object by name.

Comment: Is the better option to move `CameraPositionHandler` into the player object?

Comment: Try using the non-generic form, `FindObjectOfType(typeof(ICameraControl))`. Or there are other decoupling patterns you can use, depending on the relationships between your objects.